# AJAX calls randomly timing out in IE6/7?

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-7

Some of my AJAX calls in IE6 and IE7 seem to randomly time out. It doesn't happen in any of the other browsers. Posting code won't be of much help, because it literally happens in three or four different places where the functions and code are completely different.

Has anyone else experienced this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a cache issue. I had a similar issue, the page content was never updating on some of the calls. This was completely random.

In jQuery AJAX method options you can set:  Cache: false;

In my case the above solution did not resolve the problem, but might work in your case.